# Merge 2 columns from joined table

Tags: postgresql

lets say I have 2 tables :

```
group
{
     id,
     export boolean not null default false
}
```

and

```
channel
{
     id,
     group_id null,
     export boolean null
}
```

Is it possible, with 1 query, to request the export boolean value for a specified channel id such as :

- channel.export is not null return it as is
- if channel.export is null and channel.group_id is null return false
- if channel.export is null and channel.group_d is not null return group.export

I am using postgresql 10.

This seems a little bit hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You requirement can be translated into a CASE <s>statement</s> expression almost word for word.

```
SELECT 
CASE 
    WHEN channel.export is not null then channel.export 
    WHEN channel.group_id is null then false
    ELSE "group".export
END as merged_bool
FROM channel LEFT JOIN "group" ON (group_id="group".id);
```

Comment: great ! thank you